# Javascript Fade In (Tabs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a tab system which uses some Javascript to switch tabs. I want them to fade in and out when you switch tabs. The JS at the moment just removes and adds the clicked tab the user chooses. I have made the fade in JS kind of work however it does not remove tabs.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Tab Four</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
      Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </div>
    <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
      Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- container -->
```

Comment: Can you provide an example that shows the problem?

Comment: Here we go: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LezYdO I have tried to add a fade in function to the JS. whether I have done anything correctly....

Comment: You don't specify a concrete tab within `$('.tab-content').fadeIn("slow");` so everything is faded in. You can do this instead: `$("#"+tab_id).addClass('current').fadeIn("slow");` furthermore you have to fadeOut before you fadeIn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **`fadeIn()`** jQuery function to fadeIn your tabs. You have to replace some lines in your script code as

**1st**

```
$('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
```

to

```
$('.tab-content').removeClass('current').hide();
```

**2nd:**

```
$("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
```

to

```
$("#" + tab_id).addClass('current').fadeIn();
```

> More help on [**Fading jQuery**](https://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current').hide();
    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current').fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content.current {
  display: block;
}

.tabs {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.tabs li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabs li.current {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: initial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Tab Four</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
      Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </div>
    <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
      Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

You are most of the way there.

A very simple solution, since you are already using jquery would be to use fadeIn and fadeOut.

Something like this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var last_id;
    $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

        // Fade out elements with tab-content class
        $('.tab-content').fadeOut( "slow");

        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');

        // fade out the last content
        if(last_id) $("#"+last_id).fadeOut();
        // Fade in the element you want to show
        $("#"+tab_id).fadeIn( "slow");
        last_id = tab_id;
    })
})
```

More info on both fade in and fade out are available at
http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/
http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var selectedtab;
    $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
        if(selectedtab) $("#"+selectedtab).hide();
        $("#"+tab_id).fadeIn("slow");
        selectedtab = tab_id;
        $(this).addClass('current');
    })
})
```

Used a variable to store the tab_id of the selected tab.

Comment: Thank you for this!